# how to use a flag to return only one group using findall- Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, request

I'm working on using code for art (if that's possible?) and I'm trying to retrieve the third group of a regex using `findall`. I read the official docs on `findall` and find it returning a tuple a bit lacking, I wanted to pass in a flag to return the third group, not a tuple of 3 groups (the first two were placeholders). What is the most efficient way to chain something on to return only names (the third group) instead of iterating through afterward?

```
import re, requests

rgx = r"([<][TDtd][>])|(target[=]new[>])(?P<the_deceased>[A-Z].*?)[,]"

urls = {2013: "http://www.killedbypolice.net/kbp2013.html",
        2014: "http://www.killedbypolice.net/kbp2014.html",
        2015: "http://www.killedbypolice.net/" }

names_of_the_dead = []

for url in urls.values():
    response = requests.get(url)
    content = response.content
    people_killed_by_police_that_year_alone = re.findall(rgx, content)
    for dead_person in people_killed_by_police_that_year_alone:
        names_of_the_dead.append(dead_person)

#dead_americans_as_string = ",".join(names_of_the_dead)
#print("RIP, {} since 2013:\n".format(len(names_of_the_dead)))
#print(dead_americans_as_string)

In [67]: names_of_the_dead
Out[67]: 
[('', 'target=new>', 'May 1st - Dec 31st'),
 ('', 'target=new>', 'Ricky Junior Toney'),
 ('', 'target=new>', 'William Jackson'),
 ('', 'target=new>', 'Bethany Lytle'),
 ('', 'target=new>', 'Christopher George'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUst turn first and second capturing groups as non-capturing groups.

```
rgx = r"(?:[<][TDtd][>])|(?:target[=]new[>])(?P<the_deceased>[A-Z].*?)[,]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an HTML data you are parsing, why not use a specialized tool for it - an HTML Parser, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). The idea would be to iterate over table rows and get the 4th column text:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urls = {2013: "http://www.killedbypolice.net/kbp2013.html",
        2014: "http://www.killedbypolice.net/kbp2014.html",
        2015: "http://www.killedbypolice.net/" }

names_of_the_dead = []

for url in urls.values():
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    for row in soup.select("table tr")[2:]:
        cells = row.find_all("td")
        if len(cells) > 3:
            names_of_the_dead.append(cells[3].text.split(",")[0].strip())

print(names_of_the_dead)
```

Comment: that's what I wanted alec. I don't think those extra 700 people should have died in vain, to not have their name remembered. gracias mucho

Comment: for some reason it isn't working. i'll work on it this week

In [17]: print(names_of_the_dead)
[]